# SetRootIndex in QML PathView

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm using a QML `PathView` to show my model. Such a model inherits from [`QStandardItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel-members.html) and has two levels of data (parent items and child items). I need to show the second level of the model in the PathView, i.e. all the children of a selected parent. Using a [`QAbstractItemView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) this result can be achieve by using the `setRootIndex` function. How can I achieve the same result with a `PathView`?

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Here a model example:

```
newPetModel::newPetModel()
{
...
 fillModel();
}
...
void newPetModel::fillModel()
{
 QStandardItem* rootItem = invisibleRootItem();
 // groups
 QStandardItem* GroupAnimals = new QStandardItem();
 rootItem->setChild(rootItem->rowCount(), GroupAnimals);
 GroupAnimals->setData(QString("Animals"),nameRole);

 QStandardItem* GroupPlants = new QStandardItem();
 rootItem->setChild(rootItem->rowCount(), GroupPlants);
 GroupPlants->setData(QString("Plants"),nameRole);

 QStandardItem* GroupInsects = new QStandardItem();
 rootItem->setChild(rootItem->rowCount(), GroupInsects);
 GroupInsects->setData(QString("Insects"),nameRole);
 // items
 QStandardItem* Cat = new QStandardItem();
 GroupAnimals->setChild(GroupAnimals->rowCount(), Cat);
 Cat->setData(QString("Cat"),nameRole);
 Cat->setData(QString("qrc:/cat.jpg"),imgRole);

 QStandardItem* Dog = new QStandardItem();
 GroupAnimals->setChild(GroupAnimals->rowCount(), Dog);
 Dog->setData(QString("Dog"),nameRole);
 Dog->setData("qrc:/dog.jpg",imgRole);`enter code here`
 //-----
 QStandardItem* Peas = new QStandardItem();
 GroupPlants->setChild(GroupPlants->rowCount(), Peas);
 Peas->setData(QString("Peas"),nameRole);
 Peas->setData("qrc:/peas.jpg",imgRole);
 //-----
 QStandardItem* Spider = new QStandardItem();
 GroupInsects->setChild(GroupInsects->rowCount(), Spider);
 Spider->setData(QString("Spider"),nameRole);
 Spider->setData("qrc:/peas.jpg",imgRole);

 QStandardItem* Fly = new QStandardItem();
 GroupInsects->setChild(GroupInsects->rowCount(), Fly);
 Fly->setData(QString("Fly"),nameRole);
 Fly->setData("qrc:/fly.jpg",imgRole);
}
```

Comment: First and foremost, is your model available in QML? Have you added it as a context property?

Comment: Model added as context property by function setContextProperty and model property of PathView is setted. PathView shows first level of items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QML works with list models, as you have seen also in your case. However, this limitation can be easily overcome by using [`DelegateModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html). Quoting the documentation:

> It is usually not necessary to create a DelegateModel. However, **it can be useful for manipulating and accessing the modelIndex when a QAbstractItemModel subclass is used as the model**. Also, DelegateModel is used together with Package to provide delegates to multiple views, and with DelegateModelGroup to sort and filter delegate items.

Such QML type has a property [`rootIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html#rootIndex-prop). Quoting again the documentation:

> QAbstractItemModel provides a hierarchical tree of data, whereas QML only operates on list data. **rootIndex allows the children of any node in a QAbstractItemModel to be provided by this model**.

This is the property you need to set (and reset), as described in the example of the linked documentation. Note that by using `DelegateModel` the delegate in your `PathView` should not be defined. A working example (`visualdatamodel/slideshow.qml`) is available in the standard framework distribution under the path:

```
Qt/QtXXX/Examples/Qt-5.4/quick/views
```

Finally note that `DelegateModel` and [`VisualDataModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-visualdatamodel.html) are often used in an interchangeable way since

> This type (*VisualDataModel*) is provided by the Qt QML module due to compatibility reasons. **The same implementation is now primarily available as DelegateModel in the Qt QML Models** module.

Comment: DelegateModel is what I need. Thanks! And sorry for my english

Comment: No problem. Look for my edit...I remembered there was an example in the standard framework distribution. That should clarify any (possible) doubt.