# Can the part of QAbstractListModel be used as model for QML views?

Tags: c++, qt, mvvm, qml, qtquick2

I inherited `QAbstractListModel`. Now I want to use part of this model as `model` for `gridView1` and part of it as `model` for `gridView2`. Can I do this? Or should I look at `QAbstractItemModel`? If so, where can I get complete example of using it in bundle with QML?

I want to create something like this:

```
ListView {
    id: listViewMain
    anchors.fill: parent
    orientation: ListView.Vertical
    model: guiModel
    delegate: GridView {
        id: gridViewMain
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: contentHeight
        interactive: false
        model: TilesSortFilterProxyModel {
            sourceModel: guiModel
        }
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 70
            height: 70
            color: model.color
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: model.msg
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But what should be used as `model` for `listViewMain` to get something like this:

[image: desired result]

Comment: A list model is simply an item model specialized to have only one column.  If that works for you then it should be fine.  You might find a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) handy for splitting up the data.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added some code and picture to explain what I mean.

Comment: Is this just a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191028/how-to-combine-views-in-qml) then?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes. And I've already deleted it :) I'm trying to find the best question to describe what I want.

Comment: While it could be feasible, I don't see any *logical* reason to  use the list model for all the three views. I would limit the usage of the latter to the tiles, through a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, while the `ListView` model of two "reds" and "greens" items could be created via another approach.

You can use an [`ObjectModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-objectmodel.html) for instance, or simply use a `model: 2` in the current code to generate two `GridView` delegates. Clearly each approach has pros and cons.

Comment: Finally, if you would like to go for the `QAbstractItemModel`, you can then use a unique model. The first level will contain the `ListView` items names whereas each second level will be compound of the specific set of tiles. Mind that QML only works with list models but you can easily overcome the problem: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27655785/2538363) and the related framework example, cited in the end.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo that is exactly the question that I was trying to ask :) Using `QAbstractItemModel` as model in QML views. Can you provide a link to example of using of such a bundle? Not documentation, but complete example of using.

Comment: The edit at the end refers to an actual example in the standard library: did you checked it? I've clearly stated that the last edit is about that. Look for it.