# Extracting sub model from a another model?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The following code is from a Qt demo. This is a model for QTreeView.

`TreeItem` class below represent each node in tree, it can have child nodes.

```
class TreeItem
{
public:
    explicit TreeItem(const QList<QVariant> &data, TreeItem *parentItem = 0);
    ~TreeItem();

    void appendChild(TreeItem *child);

    TreeItem *child(int row);
    int childCount() const;
    int columnCount() const;
    QVariant data(int column) const;
    int row() const;
    TreeItem *parentItem();

private:
    QList<TreeItem*> m_childItems;
    QList<QVariant> m_itemData;
    TreeItem *m_parentItem;
};
```

`TreeModel` class below is the main model. It only contains one root node which contain all other child nodes.

```
class TreeModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TreeModel(const QString &data, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~TreeModel();

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                        int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column,
                      const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    void setupModelData(const QStringList &lines, TreeItem *parent);

    TreeItem *rootItem;
};
```

I am using QML and I can get this model displayed in tree however I also want to display in a `ListView`.

For the ListView, I only want to display one tier at one time (1st childrens). When  user click on any of the item, it should clear and show that item children. How do I do that?

My Qml code is below. It displays all first tier children which is great but I need to show children when user clicks on an item. My thought is need extract the sub model and point to it, but how?

```
Item {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    ListView {
        //anchors.top: myImage.bottom
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: list
        spacing: 4
        model: treeModel

        delegate: listDelegate

    }

    Component {
        id: listDelegate
        Rectangle
        {
            id: delegateRect
            height: image.height
            width: 500
            Image {
                id: image
                source: "qrc:/icons/resources/element.ico"

            }

            Text {
                id: t
                anchors.left: image.right
                anchors.leftMargin: 20
                anchors.centerIn: delegateRect

                text: title + "/" + summary
                //text: display
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {

                    list.currentIndex = index

                    console.log("Item clicked, index = " + index)

                    // I think I should change model here to sub model but how do I do it?
                    //list.model = treeModel.data(index) 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648701/setrootindex-in-qml-pathview/27655785#27655785) also applies here.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the QAbstractProxyModel and derived classes in the Qt documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html.

A proxy model is used to map model indexes (if you want to modify the layout, or do sorting/filtering on data) and do data processing (modify the data returned from the source models data method).

What you need to do is to add a property to select the *new root* (the item that should be the root item of the extracted model) and implement the two methods `mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &)` and `mapToSource(const QModelIndex &)`. These methods map the model index given to the view (and only valid in your proxy model) to a model index that is valid for the source model based on the currently set *root* property (and vice versa).

In addition you should also reimplement the `roleNames()` method to forward the rolenames defined by the source model to be able to access the data from inside QML.