# How to display hierarchical tables

Tags: qt, qml

I have a custom model that inherits from `QAbstractItemModel`.  It implements a two-deep list (first layer has n elements, each element has m sub-elements).  I can successfully bind a `GridView`'s model to the first layer.  How would I go about binding a nested ListView to display the second layer of elements?

```
GridView {
    model: myModel
    delegate: ColumnLayout {
        Text { text: "First layer" }
        ListView {
            model: // What do I put here?
            delegate: Text { text: "Second layer" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SetRootIndex in QML PathView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648701/setrootindex-in-qml-pathview)

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo How to show a two-deep list in one page? Awkwardly, I still don't know how to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DelegateModel.

The DelegateModel has a property called rootIndex which you can use to tell the ListView to shift the root of the model to the start of one of the sub-lists.

```
ListView {
    model: DelegateModel {
        model: myModel
        delegate: {...}
        rootIndex: index
    }
}
```

Where index is the attached propery from your GridView which points to the parent entry for your sub-entries.